# Option/Select Menu is not displayed HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple HTML file which should offer the user a select box where he/she can select multiple options.

I actually copy& paste the code from the documentary but I have nothing displayed

[image]

This is the code displayed in the browser, all links to styles and css are working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--TODO make this xmlns entries inserted by the IDE at HTML creation-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container text-center"><h2>Select</h2></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">List</div>
    <form method="post">
        <select title="select" class="selectpicker" multiple>
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>

    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>IN STOCK</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BMW</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mercedes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>

<footer>
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.3.1-1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--    <script th:src="@{/mainpage.js}"></script>-->
    <link href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</footer>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

</html>
```

and here the **IDE HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--TODO make this xmlns entries available per default creation-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container text-center"><h2>Select</h2></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">List</div>
    <form method="post">
        <select title="select" class="selectpicker" multiple>
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>

    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>IN STOCK</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="prod : ${cars}">
            <td th:text="${prod}">Onions</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>

<footer th:replace="template :: footer"></footer>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

</html>
```

**source**

Any idea what is the issue here?

[enter link description here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#basic-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Bootstrap CSS stylesheet and Javascript file to your document.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--TODO make this xmlns entries available per default creation-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container text-center"><h2>Select</h2></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">List</div>
    <form method="post">
        <select title="select" class="selectpicker" multiple>
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>

    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>IN STOCK</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="prod : ${cars}">
            <td th:text="${prod}">Onions</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>

<footer th:replace="template :: footer"></footer>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

</html>
```

Comment: Ty. Mhm, first of all I have all these js and css files already in my HTML doc (look footer). Second, this should be used with bootstrap 4. I tried it with your suggestion (replaced with bootstrap 4) and now I see at least a select field but clicking on it, it doesn't open.

Comment: @AnnaKlein I changed to Bootstrap4.

Comment: It is working now, thank you a lot. But I still don't understand why it didn't work before. As you can see in my browser HTML document, I have the same dependencies of Jquery, Bootstrap etc loaded, but only in the footer. Does this made the difference? The firefox web documentation says actually, it doesn't usually matters?!

Comment: @AnnaKlein If they are at the bottom of the page, the styles won't be applied to any elements above them. Remember that HTML documents are parsed from top to bottom.